# Importing all the modules at one time in Python

Tags: python, module

I've a doubt.This is my second question in this site.

My Question:

Is it is possible to import all the Python modules in a single line?

I tried to create a new module that includes the importing all the modules.
And I compiled my own module using py_compiler.
But when I import my module, it doesn't call any functions in the module

Comment: you might want to use `from module import *` to import all of the functions from a module, if I understand you correctly

Comment: I'm sry,  I want to import all the modules... Not the functions

Comment: I don't know if that is what you want to do but you can separate python statements with a semicolon `;`. You can also merge two or more import statements like this: `import modulex, moduley`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this probably isn't what you want, and I don't know why you'd want this, but here's code to import every module on the system.

```
import pkgutil
mod_list = [a.name for a in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
for mod in mod_list:
    print('importing %s...' % mod)
    try:
        exec('import %s' % mod)
        print('imported %s' % mod)
    except:
        print('failed to import %s' % mod)
print(dir())
```

Note that to call a function from a module, you'd still have to type `module.func()`.